# How to sum all debit,credit per vendorname and Get the balance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi Good day I got problem with this I want the result of my data to sum all my result per Vendorname, Total amount for per vendor, total paid per vendor  and get the balance per Per Vendorname.

sample codes

```
    select a.vendorname,b.acct,c.description as Acct_Description,b.debit,b.credit
from  (select cdvno,acct
        , sum(case when credit = 0 then debit else 0 end) as debit
        , sum(case when debit = 0 then credit else 0 end) credit
        , trantype
    from cdvdtl  

    group by cdvno,acct, trantype    
) b
left join cdvhdr a
     on b.cdvno = a.cdvno and b.trantype = a.trantype
left join account c
on b.acct = c.acct
where b.acct= '2122102'
order by vendorname asc`
```

result is like this i  get multiple result for vendorname I want to show the result, 1 result each vendorname and total amount for all the transaction

```
  vendorname                    acct    Acct_Description    debit   credit
3-TECH INNOVATION MASTER CORP.  2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    40095.00
3-TECH INNOVATION MASTER CORP.  2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  40095.00    0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  706811.77   0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  851490.64   0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  219839.48   0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    268457.28
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    3519147.66
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  3787604.94  0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    1770.62
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    158672.78
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  1770.62 0.00
4K DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION      2122102 Accounts Payable - Contractors  0.00    376552.26
```

I Tried using partition but i didnt get what i want, I need the result to be like this

[image: This is using tableau]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after getting the `sum()` of your `item details` per `invoice number`, you need to `sum()` again for each `vendor name`.

```
select a.vendorname
    , b.acct
    , c.description as Acct_Description
    , sum(b.debit) sa debit
    , sum(b.credit) as credit
    , sum(b.debit)-sum(b.credit) as balance
from  (select cdvno,acct
        , sum(case when credit = 0 then debit else 0 end) as debit
        , sum(case when debit = 0 then credit else 0 end) credit
        , trantype
    from cdvdtl 
    group by cdvno,acct, trantype    
) b
left join cdvhdr a
     on b.cdvno = a.cdvno and b.trantype = a.trantype
left join account c on b.acct = c.acct
where b.acct= '2122102'
group by a.vendorname,  b.acct, c.description
order by a.vendorname asc
```

Comment: Wow it works.Thank you. Can you explain how do you sum per Vendorname ? :D

Comment: sum() with group by vendorname, will get you sum() for each unique vendor name.

Comment: So you can use group by to actually sum unique vendor, I thought using group by you need to add the the field debit ,credit. So thats why im not getting the result that i want.

Comment: you don't add those fields in group by that you are trying to aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the subquery or the join to `account`:

```
select ch.vendorname,
       sum(case when cd.credit = 0 then cd.debit else 0 end) as debit,
       sum(case when cd.debit = 0 then cd.credit else 0 end) as credit
from cdvdtl cd left join
     cdvhdr ch
     on cd.cdvno = ch.cdvno and bcdtrantype = ch.trantype 
where ch.acct = '2122102'
order by ch.vendorname asc
```